# Apidocjs default template not changing to new template added

Tags: templates, api-doc, slate

I now have installed new template into my computer.

*https://github.com/jodacame/apidocjs-template-dark-Slate-Inspiration-*

as per the documentation in the above link shows, I've done the following:

```
git clone https://github.com/jodacame/apidocjs-template-dark-Slate-Inspiration-.git
cd yourproject

this last line I've changed a bit:
Original as per template documentation:

apidoc --template ../apidocjs-template-dark-Slate-Inspiration-/template/
```

mine:

```
apidoc --template apidocjs-template-dark-Slate-Inspiration-/template/
```

the folder structure:

project folder/
   apidocjs-template-dark-Slate-Inspiration-

apidoc.json

api_project.json

api_project.js

api_data.json

api_data.js

vendor

locales

fonts

css

And my apidoc.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "XX API Introduction",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "wemfdkmesof.......",
  "title": "Custom apiDoc browser title",
  "url" : "http://xxx/api.php/v1",
  "template": {
    "withCompare": true,
    "withGenerator": true
  }
}
```

and I always run this command to generate documentation after any changes made:

```
apidoc -f .php -i ./ -o ./
```

Please guide me why the template not changing to the new one and how do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

try adding `-t path/to/template` every time you update the doc

eg.

```sh
apidoc -f .php -i ./ -o ./ -t ./apidocjs-template-dark-Slate-Inspiration-/template/
```